# Max size of post data for export to har in fiddler

Tags: http, https, fiddler

Fiddler wont export post data body when it exceeds a max limit. (what is the max limit)

Recently I came across a post data body with a field value with a size of approx 75000 chars (and content length is 122042
), I assume this is above the limit set in fiddler.

This results in the field showing a blank value in 'Web Form' tab.

Also when exporting these sessions to an har file, the post data in completely ignored.

Is there a place we can change the max chars allowed?

I have tested this on fiddler classic as well as fiddler everywhere.

Comment: Have you tried to increase `fiddler.importexport.HTTPArchiveJSON.MaxBinaryBodyLength` as described [here](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledge-base/importexportformats)?

Comment: @Robert Yes I tried that but has no effect. Received a response from Telerik. They say it indeed is a limitation and have marked it as a feature request. Here is the link https://www.telerik.com/account/support-tickets/view-ticket/1532655